# Why am I getting 'undefined' error when variable already defined

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
 <link href="/content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="/content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        datasource123 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                     url:"http://localhost/KendoServices/Web/GetProductDetails",
                     dataType: 'jsonp'
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $('#products').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource123
    });
</script>
```

Getting exception:

> 'datasource123' undefined !!

Comment: I think variable `datasource123` is defined in the document-ready handler scope. also you should move `$('#products').kendoGrid({
dataSource: datasource123 });` in document-ready handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datasource123` isn't defined until document ready, but `dataSource: datasource123` executes before that. I think you can move it inside document ready and have the variable scoped to the function...

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var datasource123 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                     url:"http://localhost/KendoServices/Web/GetProductDetails",
                     dataType: 'jsonp'
                }
            }
        });
        $('#products').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: datasource123
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The creation of your `DataSource` is being done in a jQuery ready function which will NOT run until the DOM is ready.  Your first use of `datasource123` is being done immediately.  So `datasource123` will not be created until after you try to use it.

I would suggest this change to put them both in the jQuery ready function and to declare your `datasource123` variable in a given scope so it is not an implicit global:

```
$(function () {
    var datasource123 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                 url:"http://localhost/KendoServices/Web/GetProductDetails",
                 dataType: 'jsonp'
            }
        }
    });
    $('#products').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource123
    });
});
```